# Exception emask 0x0 SAct in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, data-recovery, data-corruption

[image: Error picture]

Basically when I try to get into the ubuntu, the error is coming.

Please help me out with this.

EDIT : It might be useful for others. So basically my hard disk was corrupted in which ubuntu is stored. Also tried to recover the data, but was too late. And lost all the data in my ubuntu.
So better when you get this error, quickly start recovering the data as much as possible.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466376/boot-error-emask-0x0-sact-0x0-serr-0x0-action-0x6-frozen Do a search with the error message and it appears to possibly be a hardware issue.

Comment: guiverc Oh! Sorry i didn't knew about that. It's 20.04

Comment: @KGIII yes. I have already referenced the link you sent. The error is some what different specified over there.